# Is there anything wrong with this scheme for error logging?

Tags: c++

I wrote this interface:

```
//The idea is to use EHPrint to construct the error msg and then raise an error or
//a warning, etc. This removes the need to implement all 3 'Raise' functions
//as taking variable param list reducing code.                                                   
class ErrorHandler                                                            
{   
    public:
        virtual void RaiseError(bool, int) = 0;                     
        virtual void RaiseWarning(int) = 0;                                   
        virtual void RaiseMsg() = 0;                                          

        __attribute__((format(printf, 1, 2)))
        virtual const char* EHPrint(const char*, ...) = 0;                    

        virtual ~ErrorHandler(){}                                             
};
```

Forget multi-threading issues because one object will only be used in one thread. Implementation classes can log, raise errors to user or terminate as needed. The drawback is that you have to call `EHPrint` before you want to raise an error, etc. Any way I can make this more beautiful?

EDIT:
    I'd really like to just call one function when I want to `RaiseError`. As of now, I have to call `EHPrintf` and then call `RaiseError`.

EDIT2:
    I think it is my mistake that I coupled error handling and error logging together. Will try and separate them and see.

EDIT3:
    I thought I should post the logger now:

```
class Logger                                                        
{   
    public:
        enum LogType                                                
        {   
            LT_DEBUG = 0,                                           
            LT_WARNING,                                             
            LT_ERROR,                                               
            LT_STAT,                                                
            LT_TEXT                                                 
        };                                                          

        __attribute__((format(printf, 5, 6)))                       
        virtual const char* EHLog(LogType,                          
                int,
                const char*,                                        
                int,
                const char*,                                        
                ...) = 0;                                           

        virtual ~Logger(){}                                         
};
```

Which clears up the code because logging is separate now.

Comment: Check out the existing open source logging libraries(log4cxx, Pantheios) to get an idea ?

Comment: I'd like an answer to this specific problem. Those libs are huge and I don't feel like going through them atm. :)

Comment: Don't need to go through the code. Atleast skim through the header files to get an idea of sorts !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most logging libraries that support multiple levels of logmessages use only one function for generating the messages and this function takes an additional parameter indicating the level of the log message.

In your structure, that could look like this:

```
class ErrorHandler                                                            
{   
    private:
        virtual void RaiseError(bool, int) = 0;                     
        virtual void RaiseWarning(int) = 0;                                   
        virtual void RaiseMsg() = 0;                                          
    public:
        enum LogLevel {
            ERROR,
            WARNING,
            MSG
        };

        __attribute__((format(printf, 2, 3)))
        virtual const char* EHPrint(enum LogLevel, const char*, ...) = 0;                    

        virtual ~ErrorHandler(){}                                             
};
```

Some additional points you have to consider:

1. Variadic functions are not safe to use with non-POD types. If you use printf-style functions for logging, your users are restricted to logging only primitive types. A class like `std::string` *can not* be used.
2. With the two-call setup for preparing the message and sending it, you must be prepared that users call `EHPrint` multiple times before calling one of the `RaiseXXX` functions.

Furthermore, I second the comment from DumbCoder to take a look at existing logging libraries, if only to see what they have in common in their design and/or API.

Comment: The thing is, we already have a logging lib. This class is not supposed to be an error logger but an error handler. It was my mistake in the title. Will edit. That makes it clear for me also. Error handling and error message logging should be separate. I''ll do that. Thanks for the suggestions.